# uax_url_email tokenizer in elasticsearch generates multiple tokens for emails with special characters

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, tokenize, analyzer

I use uax_url_email tokenizer for email fields in our index. It works perfect and generates single token for normal emails like johndoe@yahoo.com. However it generates multiple tokens when the email has foreign or special characters. Is there a solution for this ? I don't want multiple tokens generated

```json
PUT email-test-index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "email_analyzer": {
            "filter": ["lowercase"],
            "tokenizer": "email_tokenizer"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "email_tokenizer": {
            "type": "uax_url_email"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "date_detection": false,
    "numeric_detection": false,
    "properties": {
      "EMAIL": {
        "type": "text",
        "store": true,
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "email_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When it work:

```json
GET email-test-index/_analyze
{
  "field": "EMAIL",
  "text": "johndoe@yahoo.com"
}

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "johndoe@yahoo.com",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 17,
      "type" : "<EMAIL>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

When it does not work:

```json
GET email-test-index/_analyze
{
  "field": "EMAIL",
  "text": "johndoeó8@yahoo.com"
}

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "johndoeó8",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "yahoo.com",
      "start_offset" : 10,
      "end_offset" : 19,
      "type" : "<URL>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am afraid the `ó` is not a valid char for an email address. Enhance it is not recognised as one.

Answer (score 1):

## Tldr;

You can not without getting rid of the special char.
I might be wrong but I don't think such char are even allowed by the email standard.

## Solution

You could be using the mapping char filter and catch all non ascii char at map them to ascii.

```json
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
  "char_filter": [
    {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [
        "ó => o"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "text": "Email me at johndóe8@yahoo.com"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Email",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "me",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "at",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "johndoe8@yahoo.com",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 30,
      "type": "<EMAIL>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that the `ó` has been replaced by 'o'

Comment: thanks. But this is not the solution I need. I don't want it to alter the original data. I just want it to preserve the original data and only produce a single email token.

Comment: Then I guess you would have to write your own tokenizer, bundle it into an elasticsearch plugin. But that a lot of work.